# How to use sleep for perf commands

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, perf, stat

Using this command : perf stat -a sleep 1
I get the stats for 'system wide ' after a pause of 1s.

Performance counter stats for 'system wide':

```
      4,004.86 msec cpu-clock                 #    3.998 CPUs utilized          
         1,430      context-switches          #    0.357 K/sec                  
            84      cpu-migrations            #    0.021 K/sec                  
            78      page-faults               #    0.019 K/sec                  
  15,21,48,844      cycles                    #    0.038 GHz                    
   5,22,40,287      instructions              #    0.34  insn per cycle         
   1,02,74,499      branches                  #    2.566 M/sec                  
      7,10,933      branch-misses             #    6.92% of all branches        

   1.001601444 seconds time elapsed
```

However I want the sleep to work for any command provided with perf stat.Example:
perf stat -e instructions python3 <nameoffile.py> sleep 1
But sleep does not seem to work for a command .
How can I pause the perf stat python3 name.py while execution?

Comment: why you want to use sleep?? you can simply collect performance stat using "perf stat -e instructions python3 <nameoffile.py>".

Comment: @ajit,I need the perf stat data on different timestamp. for example 10ms,20ms. Also I need that when i want it. For example if my python file take 30ms to execute, I want the perf stat to give me values of hardware events for 10ms and pause. I will do some dynamic analysis based on multithreading with values on that time stamp. After that is done,I want the perf stat to fetch the values for next 10ms for that python file only. Thus I need  to stop the execution.

Comment: It is possible to get stat after a every N msecs using -I flag. perf stat -e instructions -I 10 <application> will print stats every 10 ms.

Comment: Newer version of perf support "--timeout N" msec flag to stop printing stat after N milliseconds. Using --pre and --post flag you can run some command before start of perf and after end of perf.